# Writing a Robotium test to swipe open an item on a swipeable ListView

Tags: android, listview, robotium

I would like to share the way i did it with the rest of the StackOverflow community, to potentially save someone some time as i was unable to find much relevant info anywhere.

I am using a [SwipeListView](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) plugin in the app, but it should work for any other ListView as long list items swipe. I wanted to write a Robotium test that will swipe an item on the list containing specific text to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a utility method that should go into a test function in a class that extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2:

```
protected void swipeLeftOnText(String text) {
    int fromX, toX, fromY, toY;
    int[] location = new int[2];

    View row = solo.getText(text);
    row.getLocationInWindow(location);

    // fail if the view with text cannot be located in the window
    if (location.length == 0) {
         fail("Could not find text: " + text);
    }

    fromX = location[0] + 100;
    fromY = location[1];

    toX = location[0];
    toY = fromY;

    solo.drag(fromX, toX, fromY, toY, 10);
}
```